# Poor man's SSL - is this method as safe as SSL/TLS?

Tags: aes, tls

I need to send data between two applications. I've got requirement that says that data should be transmitted using secure protocol such as SSL/TLS. Data is sent using TCP sockets and I don't have built in SSL/TLS support. However, I'm able to encrypt content using AES and I'm also able to exchange small amount of data using https. I'm thinking of exchanging the key for symmetric encryption using https and then encrypt the data with AES before sending it over the network.

I'm in full control of both parties that exchange information. The keys are exchanged using SSL and I know that both parties are able to use AES. I guess there is no way anyone could decrypt the data without knowing the key. I agree that someone would be able to interrupt the transmission but it will be only noise since he would have to know the key to encrypt data with it.

Is this solution safe? Can it be compared to using SSL/TLS in terms of security? Is there some obvious security hole that I'm missing? Do you see any flaws in terms of security of the message (by it I mean that someone who is unauthorized sends his data as part of transmission or reads data from my transmission)?

Comment: Please give more information on the environment that does not provide a SSL library. You really should try to stick to well tested standards instead of inventing your own crypto.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue in SilverLight. SSL at socket level is available in third party libraries. Since SilverLight doesn't support NetworkStream abstraction using third party library basically requires rewriting transport layer in my application.

Comment: You might want to consider writing your own I/O abstraction layer. Nothing fancy, just a bunch of simple and fairly high-level methods that will take care of your I/O needs and let you change the underlying transport mechanism in one place as needed.

Comment: My method may inspire you https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62218/is-my-way-safe-to-remove-ssl-ca-cert-by-dht-and-pow-nodeid-for-a-decentralized-s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLS not only provides privacy, but also authentication:

- You can be sure you know who you speak to (at least the client knows if the server was using a certificate). (You provide this by the "HTTPS key exchange" you are doing at the start.)
- You can be sure that you speak to the same entity at the other side throughout the whole live of your connection (even if you don't know who this is, e.g. as a server with non-authenticated client).
- You can be sure that you get exactly what the other side sent, not something modified by someone between both sides.

AES (or any other block cipher) in a streaming mode (like CBC, CFB, OFB, CTR, ...) doesn't provide this guarantee. Because of this, there are various attacks at these modes which also endanger your privacy.

So make sure you are either

- using a mode of operation which also includes authentication (look for "AEAD") or
- using a normal privacy mode together with an external MAC (like HMAC) - and transfer the MAC key together with the encryption key during your key exchange).

Comment: Also, if sending data in multiple messages, remember to include a sequence number to protect against message dropping or replay attacks.

Comment: If add HMAC (e.g. Encrypt then MAC as described here http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-06-24-encrypt-then-mac.html) it should be safe in your opinion, right? Of course HMAC will use different key that would also be exchanged using https.

Comment: @empi: Yes, HMAC (with SHA-2 - don't use MD5) should be safe. Also, you'll likely have to partition your data stream in messages - then each of them should have a MAC (and a sequence number, and the MAC should cover both IV and sequence number).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Do I need sequence number if I'm sending data over tcp? I was thinking that my frame would like this: [messsage length][encrypted content][hmac]. If anyone would be able to insert segments into the tcp stream then it would be seen as noise that could potentially break the transmission (I'm not sure how the tcp library handles such case) but I don't consider it to be a security problem. What is important is that I could verify the message and it is not possible for anyone unauthorized to read the content.

Comment: @empi: TCP has no authentication build in, so it allows an attacker dropping messages or replaying previous ones (or inserting noise), as Ilmari mentioned in his comments. To prevent this, you want a message number in your crypto layer.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: In my case dropping or replaying message is not a problem - I may treat it as noise (it's a live transmission of video and audio so I may accept such cases as long as I am able to send content as fast as possible). Thanks for your comments, you've been very helpful.

Comment: If you want to combine symmetric cipher and MAC instead of using a authenticated cipher mode, it seems you should use "encrypt-then-mac" which is always secure (as opposed to "mac-then-encrypt" or "encrypt-and-mac" which may in some cases). That is you should send : E(m) || S(E(m)) where E is encrypt and S is MAC as opposed to E(m)||S(m) (encrypt-and-mac)