# Is my way safe to remove SSL CA Cert by DHT and PoW NodeID for a decentralized system?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, tls

To implement a decentralized system, I wrote a TLS like P2P net stack.
The main idea is removing CA Cert from the whole system by using a DHT for Naming and Key Exchange.
I am not a crypto expert, so if there's any flaw please point it out for me here or Github.

First, I use an Elliptic Curve for asymmetric encryption and AES-256-CBC for symmetric encryption.

DH-RPC NodeID is generated by hashing the Node PublicKey and an Uint256 Nonce:

```
NodeID := sha256(blake2b-512(NodePublicKey + Uint256Nonce))
```

I refer to S/Kademlia's idea to define the number of consecutive 0s in front of the NodeID as difficulty and to impose a minimum limit on the difficulty of the NodeID allowed to be stored on the DHT.
DHT is used to hold the NodeID:PublicKey NodeID:Addr map. NodeID and Nonce are sent to do ECDH getting shared secret after TCP connection established.

```
GenECDHSharedSecret(APub, BPriv) == GenECDHSharedSecret(BPub, APriv)
```

The main procedure is described in this sequence chart:
[image]

Because in the decentralized system NodeID is the URI, not "Bob/Alice.com". So anyone tries to fake NodeB by overwriting the address or public key on DHT without the private key of NodeB will be failed to get the correct shared secret.

[Github](https://github.com/CovenantSQL/CovenantSQL/tree/develop/rpc)

Known issues:

1. Add a random uint64 along with NodeID and Nonce sent to remote to add some random for the shared key.

Comment: In a Kademlia DHT the NodeIDs is supposed to be uniformly distributed. Defining the number of consecutive 0s in front of the NodeID as difficulty will break that.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this issue can be solved by reversing the byte order or hashing before distributing on DHT.